# HaProxy: Fetching string from the header

Tags: regex, security, https, acl, haproxy

I have a 007 mission: set HaProxy to fetch a string from the header sent from the CDN, HaProxy will only allow HTTPS requests to the backend servers IF the string is detected.
The goal is to block non-authorized accesses other than our CDN to reach the backend servers.

The closest I have got so far.

Frontend:

```
acl allow_traffic_from_cdn req.hdr(STRING NAME HERE) -m str (STRING VALUE HERE)
http-request deny if !allow_traffic_from_cdn
```

When I try to access the server via the CDN, `haproxy.log` does show the string I was expecting but that is all about it.
Only the main page is accessible, if you try no access any other page you get error messages :(

I have been reading the documentation but I am having problems to fully understand this procedure.

So, how can I set haproxy to fetch a value from the header allowing the access, but block the access if the HTTPS request does not have it?

Thank you

...

Answer (score 1):

You can create ACL which search if the header and it value exists.
then, deny all requests missing this ACL:

```
 acl from_cdn hdr(X-my-cdn-header) -i "your header value"
 http-request deny if !from_cdn
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will test this tomorrow and report back :)
Cheers

Comment: Hey, I've added what you suggested but I am not sure if I understood it properly. Taking into consideration that the information is something like "STRING_NAME=STRING_VALUE". 

Is that "X-my-cdn-header" the STRING_NAME??

If so, I am still having the same issue, the first page is okay, everything else fails :(

Thank you

Comment: Can you post example of the header you are trying to filter?
in my answer "X-my-cdn-header" is the HTTP Header name you are appending from the CDN and the -i "your header value" is the header value

Comment: sorry for the late reply.

This is the header info HaProxy is supposed to search for before accepting the HTTP request: set req.http.SECRET = "SECRET_VALUE";
If the HTTP header request does not have that value, the request is denied.

Thank you.